# scrapy crawlspider output

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm having an issue running through the [CrawlSpider example](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example) in the Scrapy documentation. It seems to be crawling just fine but I'm having trouble getting it to output to a CSV file (or anything really).

So, my question is can I use this:

```
scrapy crawl dmoz -o items.csv
```

or do I have to create an [Item Pipeline](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html)?

UPDATED, now with code!:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from targets.item import TargetsItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'abc'
    allowed_domains = ['ididntuseexample.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.ididntuseexample.com']

    rules = (
    # Extract links matching 'category.php' (but not matching 'subsection.php')
    # and follow links from them (since no callback means follow=True by default).
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('ididntuseexample.com', ))),

)

    def parse_item(self, response):
       self.log('Hi, this is an item page! %s' % response.url)
       item = TargetsItem()
       item['title'] = response.xpath('//h2/a/text()').extract() #this pulled down data in scrapy shell
       item['link'] = response.xpath('//h2/a/@href').extract()   #this pulled down data in scrapy shell
       return item
```

Comment: CSV, along with JSON and XML, is one of the out of the box export formats. So, yes, `scrapy crawl dmoz -o items.csv` should work. Could you elaborate on the troubles you are getting?

Comment: that just it, everything seems fine. no errors in the output log, it creates the file but there's just nothing in it when i open the csv. everything worked beautifully when i worked through the tutorial with the base spider, which is why i asked.

Comment: Are you using exactly the same code as it is in the CrawlSpider example? I mean, have you changed the `start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']` line?

Comment: Could you edit your question with the spider code? I'm asking all this because I suspect your spider is actually not getting any data, and hence, an empty CSV is generated.

Comment: added to code. i had to change the domain but i definitely didn't use example.com (though i appreciate you asking). i also ran the xpath through the shell and it pulled back data, so i'm reasonably certain that's not the issue either. regardless, thanks for taking a look, dreyescat!

Comment: Is your `parse_item` being called?. I don't see your `Rule` having it as callback. Or maybe did you mean `parse` instead?

Comment: from what i understand if i use `parse` it will override the `parse` method and break my crawl spider (not that its working now). so, it has to be the lack of `parse_item`. would it be something like this? `Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('ididntuseexample.com', callback='parse_item')))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rules are the mechanism `CrawlSpider` uses for following links. Those links are defined with a `LinkExtractor`. This element basically indicates which links to extract from the crawled page (like the ones defined in the `start_urls` list) to be followed. Then you can pass a callback that will be called on each extracted link, or more precise, on the pages downloaded following those links.

Your rule must call the `parse_item`. So, replace:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('ididntuseexample.com', ))),
```

with:

```
Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('ididntuseexample.com',)), callback='parse_item),
```

This rule defines that you want to call `parse_item` on every link whose `href` is `ididntuseexample.com`. I suspect that what you want as link extractor is not the domain, but the links you want to follow/scrape.

Here you have a basic example that crawls [Hacker News](https://news.ycombinator.com/) to retrieve the title and the first lines of the first comment for all the news in the main page.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class HackerNewsItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    comment = scrapy.Field()

class HackerNewsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'hackernews'
    allowed_domains = ['news.ycombinator.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://news.ycombinator.com/'
    ]
    rules = (
        # Follow any item link and call parse_item.
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('item.*', )), callback='parse_item'),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        item = HackerNewsItem()
        # Get the title
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "title")]/a/text()').extract()
        # Get the first words of the first comment
        item['comment'] = response.xpath('(//*[contains(@class, "comment")])[1]/font/text()').extract()
        return item
```

Comment: the rules object isn't absolutely necessary or is it for scraper `CrawlSpiders`?

Comment: also, in this context is `HackerNewsItem()` the class that applies the `field objects` or something?